# Making a YouTube poster frame from a Blogger post appear in Pinterest

Tags: youtube, blogger, pinterest

I have blog posts in a blogger.com blog where generally each post will have an embedded YouTube video. When one of these posts is pinned on Pinterest, I want the video's poster frame to show up as the pin's image. Currently, Pinterest isn't finding any image to show.

Pinterest's developer page on [Article Pins](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/articles/) says they support Open Graph tags and schema.org/Article properties, so I tried adding this to my post:

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://img.youtube.com/vi/[video ID]/hqdefault.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://img.youtube.com/vi/[video ID]/hqdefault.jpg" />
```

...but that didn't help. Yes, I double checked that the image URL is valid.

Comment: You should just be able to add `data-pin-url="<site_url>"` to your Pinnable images, and pinit.js will use that. `<img src="<src>" data-pin-url="<other_url>" />`

Comment: But it's not an img, it's a YouTube video in an iframe.

Comment: You can also set data-pin-media for a url to the image/video/gif

Comment: You mean set a `data-pin-media` property on the `iframe`?